# How to improve mongoDb query performance?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, database-performance

I have a collection named `Codes`. This is how the `Schema` is defined:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
import autoIncrement from 'mongoose-auto-increment';

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const CodesSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    configId: { type: Number },
    campaignId: { type: Number },
    permissions: {
      all: { type: Boolean, default: false },
      users: { type: [Number], default: [] }
    }
)

autoIncrement.initialize(mongoose.connection);
CodesSchema.plugin(autoIncrement.plugin, { model: 'Codes', field: 'campaignId' });
export default mongoose.model('Codes', CodesSchema)
```

There is one query that looks like this:

```
const query = {
  $and:[
    {$or: [
      {'permissions.all': true},
      {'permissions.users': 12}
    ]},
    {configId: 3}
  ]
};

Codes.find(query, (err, res) => {
  // do something with the result
})
```

This works fine, but if there is a huge number of documents in the database then this query is really slow.

Is there anything I can do to improve the performance of this specific query? I'm thinking that `createIndex` would help, but I'm not sure if that can be applied since there are `$and` and `$or` conditions.

**UPDATE**

I've added indexes this way:

```
CodesSchema.index({configId: 1, 'permissions.all': 1, 'permissions.users': 1});
```

But running the query with `.explain('executionStats')` option returns:

```
{
    "executionSuccess" : true,
    "nReturned" : 6,
    "executionTimeMillis" : 0,
    "totalKeysExamined" : 10,
    "totalDocsExamined" : 10,
}
```

Which doesn't seems right because the number of docs examined is greater than the number of docs returned.

Comment: It can. Give it a try and check index usage with [explain](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/)

Comment: Is `indexFilterSet` what I should be looking for? If yes, then it's set to `false`.

Comment: No, you should be looking for https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/ . And https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#indexes I guess. You are using mongoose, aren't you?

Comment: Yes, I'm using mongoose

Comment: If I set `index: true` to the `configId` field then that should be enough for improving the performance of that query?

Comment: Does anything deter you from trying? The question and the follow-up comments show no research efforts.

Comment: Sorry, I've updated the question. I did research to see how the indexes can be added and how they help, but I'm not sure if I set them correctly considering the conditions from my query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index itself is correct.

It must be `CodesSchema.index`, not `Code.index`.

Ensure you call [`Code.syncIndexes`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.syncIndexes) to update indexes dbside.

The "explain" part - you should check `winningPlan`.

If no indexes are used by the query, it should be something like

```
    "winningPlan" : {
        "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
        "filter" : {
```

When the index is being used it changes to

```
    "winningPlan" : {
        "stage" : "FETCH",
        "inputStage" : {
            "stage" : "OR",
            "inputStages" : [ 
                {
                    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                    "keyPattern" : {
```

Comment: Inspecting the `winningPlan` shows that all indexes are used. I've tried to create the indexes one by one (instead of using multi indexes like in the provided example) and the total number of evaluated documents is reduced with almost 50%, but the `rejectedPlans` returns 1 object ... is that wrong?

Comment: Basically I'm asking if something is wrong when there are rejected plans

Comment: Please read the docs https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/ and understand the difference between simple indexes, compound indexes and covered queries. `RejectedPlans` is a list of possible queries. The planner tried all of them to pick the most performant one. You will always have them if there is more than one way to fulfil the query.

Comment: To provide additionnal informations, take care of index size and writing performance with this index : as your permissions.users field is an array, an index entry will be created for each element of array, so your index will grow up fast when inserting data. Moreover,  as an index is sorted, adding/removing data in this array will result in an index partial rewrite. Keep it in mind when chosing indexed fields.